# How to have a set position and size on Xmonad startup

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I want to have a certain layout of windows every time I compile and start Xmonad. My current Xmonad config spawns 3 windows Htop, A sound visualizer, and an empty terminal. These spawn correctly, but it is random in nature. I want a consistent set of windows of which I specify their size and position. (on startup)

I searched problem this up and a found "Xmonad.Hooks.Place." I clearly don't really get most of the Xmonad documentation as when I try to implement one of the modules in my code, I almost invariably get a compiler error.

Usually, this is me going about a ham-fisted way of trying to write correct Haskell. But, at the end of the day, I don't know any Haskell. It is just a configuration language to me.

May anyone provide me with the standard way of spawning windows with a specified position and size. (assuming this is possible and is consistent with every recompilation)

This would be my Xmonad config.

```
--my XMonad Config
--xterm, contrib, feh, and nitrogen are used here

import XMonad
import Data.Monoid
import XMonad.Util.Run
import XMonad.Layout.Gaps
import XMonad.Util.SpawnOnce
import XMonad.Layout.Spacing
import System.Exit
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import qualified DBus as D
import qualified DBus.Client as D
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import qualified Codec.Binary.UTF8.String as String
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig(additionalKeys)
import System.IO
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import qualified Data.Map        as M
import Graphics.X11.ExtraTypes.XF86

-- The preferred terminal program, which is used in a binding below and by
-- certain contrib modules.
--
myTerminal      = "xterm"

-- Whether focus follows the mouse pointer.
myFocusFollowsMouse :: Bool
myFocusFollowsMouse = True

-- Whether clicking on a window to focus also passes the click to the window
myClickJustFocuses :: Bool
myClickJustFocuses = False

-- Width of the window border in pixels.
--
myBorderWidth   = 2

-- modMask lets you specify which modkey you want to use. The default
-- is mod1Mask ("left alt").  You may also consider using mod3Mask
-- ("right alt"), which does not conflict with emacs keybindings. The
-- "windows key" is usually mod4Mask.
--
myModMask       = mod1Mask

-- The default number of workspaces (virtual screens) and their names.
-- By default we use numeric strings, but any string may be used as a
-- workspace name. The number of workspaces is determined by the length
-- of this list.
--
-- A tagging example:
--
-- > workspaces = ["web", "irc", "code" ] ++ map show [4..9]
--
myWorkspaces    = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]

-- Border colors for unfocused and focused windows, respectively.
--
myNormalBorderColor  = "#55f475"
myFocusedBorderColor = "#6be6ff"
 
--soda



------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Key bindings. Add, modify or remove key bindings here.
--
myKeys conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $

    -- launch a terminal
    [ ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_Return), spawn $ XMonad.terminal conf)

    -- launch dmenu
    , ((modm,               xK_d     ), spawn "dmenu_run")

    --launch ff
    , ((modm,               xK_p     ), spawn "brave")
    --vol
      , ((modm,               xK_F8     ), spawn "pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle")
      , ((modm,               xK_i      ), spawn "pactl set-sink-port 0 analog-output-speaker")
      , ((modm,               xK_o      ), spawn "pactl set-sink-port 0 analog-output-headphones")
      , ((modm,               xK_F6     ), spawn "pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ 50%")
      , ((modm,               xK_Up     ), spawn "pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +3%")
      , ((modm,               xK_Down     ), spawn "pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -3%")
      --lol
      , ((0,               xF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume    ), spawn "pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +5%")
      , ((0,               xF86XK_AudioLowerVolume    ), spawn "pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -5%")
      , ((0,               xF86XK_AudioMute     ), spawn "pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle")
    -- launch gmrun
    --, ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_p     ), spawn "gmrun")
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_v     ), spawn "virtualbox")
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_b     ), spawn "xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 0.5")
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_z     ), spawn "xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 1")

    --master settings /gnome
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_f     ), spawn "gnome-control-center")
    --eq
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_u     ), spawn "pulseeffects")

    --lock (you need i3lock installed on your system)
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_x     ), spawn "i3lock -i ~/.config/i3/spart.png")

    --fm
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_g     ), spawn "pcmanfm")
    -- close focused window
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_c     ), kill)

     -- Rotate through the available layout algorithms
    , ((modm,               xK_space ), sendMessage NextLayout)

    --  Reset the layouts on the current workspace to default
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_space ), setLayout $ XMonad.layoutHook conf)

    -- Resize viewed windows to the correct size
    , ((modm,               xK_n     ), refresh)

    -- Move focus to the next window
    , ((modm,               xK_Tab   ), windows W.focusDown)

    -- Move focus to the next window
    , ((modm,               xK_j     ), windows W.focusDown)

    -- Move focus to the previous window
    , ((modm,               xK_k     ), windows W.focusUp  )

    -- Move focus to the master window
    , ((modm,               xK_m     ), windows W.focusMaster  )

    -- Swap the focused window and the master window
    , ((modm,               xK_Return), windows W.swapMaster)

    -- Swap the focused window with the next window
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_j     ), windows W.swapDown  )

    -- Swap the focused window with the previous window
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_k     ), windows W.swapUp    )

    -- Shrink the master area
    , ((modm,               xK_h     ), sendMessage Shrink)

    -- Expand the master area
    , ((modm,               xK_l     ), sendMessage Expand)

    -- Push window back into tiling
    , ((modm,               xK_t     ), withFocused $ windows . W.sink)

    -- Increment the number of windows in the master area
    , ((modm              , xK_comma ), sendMessage (IncMasterN 1))

    -- Deincrement the number of windows in the master area
    , ((modm              , xK_period), sendMessage (IncMasterN (-1)))

    -- Toggle the status bar gap
    -- Use this binding with avoidStruts from Hooks.ManageDocks.
    -- See also the statusBar function from Hooks.DynamicLog.
    --
    -- , ((modm              , xK_b     ), sendMessage ToggleStruts)

    -- Quit xmonad
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_q     ), io (exitWith ExitSuccess))

    -- Restart xmonad
    , ((modm              , xK_q     ), spawn "xmonad --recompile; xmonad --restart")

    -- Run xmessage with a summary of the default keybindings (useful for beginners)
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_slash ), spawn ("echo \"" ++ help ++ "\" | xmessage -file -"))
    ]
    ++

    --
    -- mod-[1..9], Switch to workspace N
    -- mod-shift-[1..9], Move client to workspace N
    --
    [((m .|. modm, k), windows $ f i)
        | (i, k) <- zip (XMonad.workspaces conf) [xK_1 .. xK_9]
        , (f, m) <- [(W.greedyView, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask)]]
    ++

    --
    -- mod-{w,e,r}, Switch to physical/Xinerama screens 1, 2, or 3
    -- mod-shift-{w,e,r}, Move client to screen 1, 2, or 3
    --
    [((m .|. modm, key), screenWorkspace sc >>= flip whenJust (windows . f))
        | (key, sc) <- zip [xK_w, xK_e, xK_r] [0..]
        , (f, m) <- [(W.view, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask)]]


------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Mouse bindings: default actions bound to mouse events
--
myMouseBindings (XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $

    -- mod-button1, Set the window to floating mode and move by dragging
    [ ((modm, button1), (\w -> focus w >> mouseMoveWindow w
                                       >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- mod-button2, Raise the window to the top of the stack
    , ((modm, button2), (\w -> focus w >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- mod-button3, Set the window to floating mode and resize by dragging
    , ((modm, button3), (\w -> focus w >> mouseResizeWindow w
                                       >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- you may also bind events to the mouse scroll wheel (button4 and button5)
    ]

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Layouts:

-- You can specify and transform your layouts by modifying these values.
-- If you change layout bindings be sure to use 'mod-shift-space' after
-- restarting (with 'mod-q') to reset your layout state to the new
-- defaults, as xmonad preserves your old layout settings by default.
--
-- The available layouts.  Note that each layout is separated by |||,
-- which denotes layout choice.
--
myLayout = tiled ||| Mirror tiled ||| theg ||| Full
  where
    tiled = spacing 35 $ Tall nmaster delta ratio
    theg = gaps [(U,18), (R,23)] $ Tall 1 (3/100) (1/2)
    nmaster = 1
    ratio = 1/2
    delta = 3/100
     

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Window rules:

-- Execute arbitrary actions and WindowSet manipulations when managing
-- a new window. You can use this to, for example, always float a
-- particular program, or have a client always appear on a particular
-- workspace.
--
-- To find the property name associated with a program, use
-- > xprop | grep WM_CLASS
-- and click on the client you're interested in.
--
-- To match on the WM_NAME, you can use 'title' in the same way that
-- 'className' and 'resource' are used below.
--
myManageHook = composeAll
    [ className =? "MPlayer"        --> doFloat
    , className =? "Gimp"           --> doFloat
    , resource  =? "desktop_window" --> doIgnore
    , resource  =? "kdesktop"       --> doIgnore ]

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Event handling

-- * EwmhDesktops users should change this to ewmhDesktopsEventHook
--
-- Defines a custom handler function for X Events. The function should
-- return (All True) if the default handler is to be run afterwards. To
-- combine event hooks use mappend or mconcat from Data.Monoid.
--
myEventHook = mempty

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Status bars and logging

-- Perform an arbitrary action on each internal state change or X event.
-- See the 'XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog' extension for examples.
--
myLogHook = return ()

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Startup hook

-- Perform an arbitrary action each time xmonad starts or is restarted
-- with mod-q.  Used by, e.g., XMonad.Layout.PerWorkspace to initialize
-- per-workspace layout choices.
--
-- By default, do nothing.
myStartupHook :: X ()
myStartupHook = do
     spawn "nitrogen --restore &"
     spawn "picom &"
     spawn "uxterm vis"
     spawn "uxterm"
     spawn "uxterm bashtop"
     spawn "xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr"


------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Now run xmonad with all the defaults we set up.

-- Run xmonad with the settings you specify. No need to modify this.
--
main = do
     xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar -x 0 /home/cotl1/.config/taskbarrc"
     xmonad $ docks defaults


-- A structure containing your configuration settings, overriding
-- fields in the default config. Any you don't override, will
-- use the defaults defined in xmonad/XMonad/Config.hs
--
-- No need to modify this.
--
defaults = def {
      -- simple stuff
        terminal           = myTerminal,
        focusFollowsMouse  = myFocusFollowsMouse,
        clickJustFocuses   = myClickJustFocuses,
        borderWidth        = myBorderWidth,
        modMask            = myModMask,
        workspaces         = myWorkspaces,
        normalBorderColor  = myNormalBorderColor,
        focusedBorderColor = myFocusedBorderColor,

      -- key bindings
        keys               = myKeys,
        mouseBindings      = myMouseBindings,

      -- hooks, layouts
        layoutHook         = myLayout,
        manageHook         = myManageHook,
        handleEventHook    = myEventHook,
        logHook            = myLogHook,
        startupHook        = myStartupHook
    }

-- | Finally, a copy of the default bindings in simple textual tabular format.
help :: String
help = unlines ["The default modifier key is 'alt'. Default keybindings:",
    "",
    "-- launching and killing programs",
    "mod-Shift-Enter  Launch xterminal",
    "mod-p            Launch dmenu",
    "mod-Shift-p      Launch gmrun",
    "mod-Shift-c      Close/kill the focused window",
    "mod-Space        Rotate through the available layout algorithms",
    "mod-Shift-Space  Reset the layouts on the current workSpace to default",
    "mod-n            Resize/refresh viewed windows to the correct size",
    "",
    "-- move focus up or down the window stack",
    "mod-Tab        Move focus to the next window",
    "mod-Shift-Tab  Move focus to the previous window",
    "mod-j          Move focus to the next window",
    "mod-k          Move focus to the previous window",
    "mod-m          Move focus to the master window",
    "",
    "-- modifying the window order",
    "mod-Return   Swap the focused window and the master window",
    "mod-Shift-j  Swap the focused window with the next window",
    "mod-Shift-k  Swap the focused window with the previous window",
    "",
    "-- resizing the master/slave ratio",
    "mod-h  Shrink the master area",
    "mod-l  Expand the master area",
    "",
    "-- floating layer support",
    "mod-t  Push window back into tiling; unfloat and re-tile it",
    "",
    "-- increase or decrease number of windows in the master area",
    "mod-comma  (mod-,)   Increment the number of windows in the master area",
    "mod-period (mod-.)   Deincrement the number of windows in the master area",
    "",
    "-- quit, or restart",
    "mod-Shift-q  Quit xmonad",
    "mod-q        Restart xmonad",
    "mod-[1..9]   Switch to workSpace N",
    "",
    "-- Workspaces & screens",
    "mod-Shift-[1..9]   Move client to workspace N",
    "mod-{w,e,r}        Switch to physical/Xinerama screens 1, 2, or 3",
    "mod-Shift-{w,e,r}  Move client to screen 1, 2, or 3",
    "",
    "-- Mouse bindings: default actions bound to mouse events",
    "mod-button1  Set the window to floating mode and move by dragging",
    "mod-button2  Raise the window to the top of the stack",
    "mod-button3  Set the window to floating mode and resize by dragging"]
```

Comment: Clarification: do you want them floated or tiled?

Comment: I would like them tiled. I should've clarified in the question. Sorry. @DanielWagner

Comment: Okay. There's no easy, out-of-the-box way to do that. Any solution will involve knowing Haskell well enough to write some actual code. You might also ping #xmonad to see if somebody there is up for writing something for you. (Just go in with the attitude of being grateful if they are, and unsurprised if they are not.)

Comment: I've implemented something like this in my config + custom layout, you might be able to extract out the code. Seems like the main functionality revolves around`windows $ modify' $ swopStackElements $ ...`

https://github.com/chrissound/XMonadLayouts/blob/master/lib/MiddleColumn.hs#L235 and https://github.com/chrissound/XMonadLayouts/blob/master/lib/RearrangeWindows.hs

Comment: @DanielWagner Would there be an out-of-the-box method for making them floated? If so, please do tell. I don't have too much of a preference. In the mean time, I will see Chris' potential solution.

Comment: @comaniac For floats, you can simply install `ManageHook`s that `doRectFloat` at the fixed positions you want them to appear at.

Comment: @DanielWagner Can I define their dimensions? I'm assuming it would be just "[X] x [Y]" next to the window I want to spawn?

Comment: @comaniac Have you looked at the Fine Manual...?

Comment: @DanielWagner I'll RTFM and come back if I'm confused.

Comment: @DanielWagner So, I did some reading on both the Arch wiki and Xmonad wiki and I found the ManageHooks/DoRectFloat. I'm only confused on how you'd get them to be a specific size.

Comment: I read the manual. How would you get the windows that spawn at the beginning to have their individual size. I tried to put DoRectFloat settings for my startup hooks and that didn't work. @DanielWagner

Comment: @comaniac You must find a way to identify the windows they create -- the usual way is by their `WM_CLASS` property -- then use those to create `ManageHook`s. If you post the output of running `xprop | grep WM_CLASS` and clicking on the windows, we can help you with that.

Comment: @DanielWagner Using Xprop on Xterm would return 'Xterm' or 'xterm' regardless of the process running in it. The problem with that is that all 3 processes on my Startup Hook are Xterm terminals. How would I differentiate them? I made a follow up question that we can continue this discussion on.